# IE CSS Issues, FireFox, Chrome Works Fine

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I have this navigation menu here which is having some IE issues. Open the following link in FF or Chrome and you will see all working fine (you need to hover over the personal and then the mobile or internet sub-menu items to test). Next if you open the same in IE 7 or 9 you will see some discrepancies. Need your help to sort this out urgently. Thanks in advance.

URL: http://h1.servy.net/sgtlmm/

Comment: What are 'discrepancies'? Problems with the images? Also, if you are interested, this JavaScript has bugs in Firefox 3.6

Comment: What bugs? Can you be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: By saying 'discrepancies' I meant that when viewed on IE7/9 there are some z-index issues. Like if you navigate to the personal > Mobile menu item you will see that the following div is appearing over the mobile menu item. Like I said, first see the page in FF or chrome and then view on IE, you will see couple of issues. Thanks for your help in advance.